# Print from iOS without any interface - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, printing

I would like to know if it is possible to print an image from an iOS device without using 'UIPrintInteractionController'. I want the image be printable only by touching a button. After searching a library, I found Core Printing which is only available for macOS... Does a similar framework or library exist for iOS ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You need a printer that you can send data to via IP or Bluetooth rather than using AirPrint; but this means you may need to create printer-specific code

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145724/ios-print-without-allowing-uiprintinteractioncontroller-to-appear

Comment: Thanks for the answers, and sorry for the duplicate, @jbtracks's answer is what I search !