# How to print right away without displaying pop-up?

Tags: swift, ipad

I am trying to print in A4 some data in swift for an iPad Apps. 
All is working perfectly but I need to click on 2 different pop-ups until getting the paper out of the printer.
I would like to print right away just after clicking on my created printing button, without viewing the print page and choosing printer.

Is it possible to save the printer somewhere so when the print button is pushed the page can be printed right away?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145724/ios-print-without-allowing-uiprintinteractioncontroller-to-appear ?

Comment: Tks Martin I will check that solution.