# javascript print without print dialog box in IOS browser

Tags: javascript, ios

Is there any option in any IOS browser to print from javascript code without opening dialog box.
For example is there option like kiosk-noprint in IOS browser?

There is no error but I cannot find any option to prevent the dialog popup

Comment: Print from iOS? You mean with a bluetooth printer?

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145724/ios-print-without-allowing-uiprintinteractioncontroller-to-appear

Comment: I have researched for the solution. But most of the questions answer for applications not browser.

Comment: No, I'm using Ethernet printer.